# A possible proof of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

By the formula 
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$$
we know that $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p \pmod{p}$,

Is there a proof of Fermat's Little Theorem based on this fact?

Comment: Yes, by induction.

Comment: My lord I'll try!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You gave the right answer sir!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Induction? Not the fact that $p$ divides $p$ choose $k$?

Comment: @Sorfosh: The OP already has established $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p \pmod p$ using the fact you mentioned. The issue at hand is how to derive Fermat's Little theorem. That will, in fact, be a proof by induction — which appears in many, many algebra texts.

Comment: @TedShifrin My bad, misunderstood

Comment: See also: [Deriving Fermat's little theorem from $(a+1)^p\equiv a^p+1$ modulo $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/266422) (The question is at least similar, maybe it could be considered even a duplicate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment by Lord Shark, using that fact, for the induction step, assuming as hypotesis $a^p\equiv a \mod p$ we have

$$(a+1)^p\equiv a^p+1\equiv a+1 \mod p$$

Comment: Thanks to @ÍgjøgnumMeg for the edit!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's bad etiquette to edit without consultation, though I suppose if consultation were required there wouldn't be an option to edit!